# jQuery widget framework alternatives

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

What jQuery widget frameworks are there? I am aware of jQuery UI, jQuery Tools and jQuery Mobile.

With jQuery widget framework I mean frameworks which provide multiple jQuery based widgets.

Comment: If you are familiar with the ones you stated, then you're familiar with all the core, mainstream frameworks available. Everything after that is piecemeal. If you want after script.aculo.us, prototype, or kineticJS you would have several other options. Thought about mastering any of those?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I am searching for jQuery based options.

Answer (score 3):

Another interesting framework is **jQuery EasyUI**:

- http://www.jeasyui.com/

It has a ton of things, from panels, layout management items, menus and buttons, to various form items (combo, pickers, grids, spinners, etc..), datagrids and complex trees..
Just take a look, it's double licensed GPL/Commercial.

It's nice to see there's a lot of development in JS UI frameworks :)

Answer (score 2):

I have used jQuery TOOLS which is an advantage to jquery UI

- http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html

Also Twitter Bootstrap provides some jQuery functions and plugins

- http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Looks like flowplayer is just a video player.

Answer (score 1):

[Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/) is a commercial JQuery based widget framework.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the
http://www.jqwidgets.com/

it is dual license.
Commercial / CC-BY-NC v3.0